# Предварительное заполнение БД

Tags: android, sqlite

У меня есть текстовые данные в формате csv. Мне нужно при первом запуске приложения перенести эту информацию в базу данных. Как лучше это сделать? Может быть, есть способ ещё на этапе разработки сделать перенос информации в Бд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как альтернативу, можно заранее создать БД SQLite рученьками, например можно использовать [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org), заботливо скормить ему CSV данные и положить в `assets`

Далее во время первого запуска скопировать готовую БД из `assets` в `Context.getDatabasePath()`

Comment: Мне видится этот вариант более быстрым...

Comment: Не возникнет ли потом проблем с миграциями?

Comment: миграцией чего?

Comment: Миграции БД. Добавление/удаление полей. Хотя если он использует ее только как хранилище статичных данных, то ничего страшного

Comment: @mifkamaz Данные будут добавляться, возможно, позже. Тогда повторю процедуру всю. Нет?

Comment: @EvgenyGooDi, при повторении операции будут потеряны пользовательские данные, т.к. ты заменишь файл БД на новый. Например: в твоей БД хранится список городов, пользователь сам заносит туда недостающие города (если такая функция в приложении есть), потом ты решаешь обновить список городов, повторяешь операцию по копированию БД, старая БД удаляется и в месте с ней ручной труд пользователя

Comment: делал по этой статье http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ . мало того что поймал SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database так еще и где-то не закрыл БД => утечки памяти. Порылся в предлагаемых вариантах решения этой проблемы. Застрял.

Answer (score 2):

Файл кладете в `assets` и при создании таблиц (у `SQLiteOpenHelper` метод `onCreate`) переносите необходимые данные из файла

Comment: Это единственный верный вариант решения моей задачи?

Comment: А как сделать чтобы парсинг начался одновременно с показом сплэш-скрина и не прервался при закрытии сплэш-скрина?  Это же возможно?

Comment: Можно создать сервис который Вы будете запускать в при первом старте приложения. Сервис будет парсить файл и заполнять БД. Сервис будет работать вне зависимости от активности(ваш кэп)